# Development requirements for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

What SDKs and other tools do I need in order to write programs that will run on a Motorola Q9M, running Windows Mobile 6 Standard? Where can I find a complete tutorial to write "hello world" for this phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the Windows Mobile SDK and the Mobile Device Center.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en#filelist

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/device-center-download.mspx

Here are some great developement resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windowsmobile/bb250560(en-us).aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/mobiledeveloper/homepage/